# What is the time complexity of the following short algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, binary-search

I am trying to design and analyse an algorithm similar to the binary search algorithm, but instead of it splitting into halves each time it splits them into either thirds or two thirds.

Here is the pseudocode for it:

```
BinarySearchThirds(A, low, high, k)
    if low == high
        if A[low] == k
            return low
        else
            return "not found"
    else
        third = third + (high-low)/3
        if key == A[mid]
            return mid
        if key < A[mid]
            return BinarySearchThirds(A, low, third - 1, k)
        else
            return BinarySearchThirds(A, third + 1, high, k)
```

I am getting that this step `return BinarySearchThirds(A, low, third - 1, k)` takes *T(n/3)* and that this step `return BinarySearchThirds(A, third + 1, high, k)` takes *T(2n/3)* and so the recurrence equation for this algorithm is *T(n) = T(2n/3) + T(n/3) + some_constant_time*

I am not sure if this recurrence equation is correct and if so how can it be transformed into a form whereby it can be solved by the master method to get it into a form of theta(...)

Comment: How likely is the number you're searching for to be in the bottom 1/3 ? How about in the top 2/3? And what do you think is the complexity of a regular binary search?

Comment: The complexity of a regular binary search is, as far as I am aware, theta(log(n)). I only require a simple time complexity estimate (without a probability distribution, so I would say the likelihood for the number being in the bottom 1/3 to be equal to the top 2/3

Comment: So yes, the binary search is O(log_2(n)).

Comment: But think about the numbers 1-100. What's the probability that it's in [1,33]? And what's the probability that it's in [34,100]? Likelihood is not equal.

Comment: Assuming that there is an equal probability that the key is at any point in the array (i.e. no one position has a higher probability than any other) then there would be a probability of 1/3 that the key is in the bottom 1/3 and a probability of 2/3 that the key is in the top 2/3.

Comment: Yes, that's my thinking as well. Since you know how to derive the classical binary search complexity, perhaps you have enough to derive your division by thirds.

Comment: This is different though, because one of the recursive calls is T(n/3) and the other is T(2n/3) while with binary search they are both T(n/2)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter whether the dividing point is at 1/2 or 2/3 or 999/1000 or whatever fraction. Whenever you have a **constant fraction**, the number of times you can multiple `n` with that fraction until you get below 1 is logarithmic in `n`. It's just the logarithmic base that changes, but the base is irrelevant in the big-o notation, since all logarithms are proportional to each other.

Hence the asymptotic time complexity must be the same as in the standard binary search algorithm, namely `O(log n)`.